# Доработать функцию PHP

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

мне нужно доработать функцию. Суть функции в том чтобы вначале каждого предложения первые буквы первых слов должны быть в верхнем регистре - функция есть, НО к примеру сокращенные слова например "т.д. т.п. др. г. чел." превращаются в "т.Д. т.П.". Я думаю можно сделать это через регулярные выражения, но я в них слаб, прошу помощи.

```
function upper_letter($text){
    $exp = ['т.д.','т.п.','др.','г.','чел.','пр.'];

    $str = $text;
    $r = preg_replace_callback(
        // добавляем модификатор u, чтобы регулярка работала с многобайтными кодировками (utf-8, utf-16)
        "/\.\s*\w/u",
        // на вход поступает каждое из найденных соответствий 
        function($m) {
            // используем mb_ функцию, так как она работает с многобайтными кодировками  
            return  mb_strtoupper($m[0]); 
        }, 
        $str
    );
    echo $r;
}

upper_letter('Я охотник. Живу в лесу.И мне комфортно и т.п') //Я охотник. Живу в лесу.И мне комфортно и т.П
```

Comment: Нельзя, это нетривиальная задача. Надо использовать специальные библиотеки nlp или самому обучать модели

Comment: а не через регулярные выражения, как-нибудь просто по типу перебора if/else или цикла в массиве нельзя строго выделить хотя бы т.д т.п др.?

Comment: Ну проверьте, идёт ли после точки пробел или нет... `/\.\ \w/u`, и все работает.

Comment: вот то что мне нужно, но нашелся еще 1 баг, в таком выражении "бизнеса и т.п. И т.д.." - союз "И" после становится заглавным, может быть как-нибудь проверяять на длину слова?

Comment: @Sergey_Safari если надо только эти 3, то можно

Answer (score 4):

Определитесь со списком исключений, и если он не слишком длинный, как указанный в функции массив `$exp`, можно доработать регулярное выражение следующим образом:

```
\b(?i:т\.д|т\.п|др|г|чел|пр|см)\b\.?(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\.\s*\w
```

См. [пример использования регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/SSXqsv/1)

На самом деле, вам, скорее всего следует заменить `\w` (которое находит любые буквы, цифры и `_`) на `\p{Ll}`, которое находит только строчные буквы:

```
\b(?i:т\.д|т\.п|др|г|чел|пр|см)\b\.?(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\.\s*\w
```

См. [пример использования регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/SSXqsv/2).

**Подробности**

- `\b` - граница слова
- `(?i:т\.д|т\.п|др|г|чел|пр|см)` - одна из строк, `т.д`, `т.п`, `др`, `г`, `чел`, `пр` или `см`
- `\b` - граница слова
- `\.?` - необязательный знак `.`
- `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` - оператор, который очищает буфер текущего совпадения и запускает поиск нового совпадения с текущей позиции в строке
- `|` - или
- `\.` - точка
- `\s*` - 0 и более пробельных символов
- `\p{Ll}` - любая строчная буква

**Обратите внимание** на массив `$exp = ['т.д','т.п','др','г','чел','пр', 'см'];`, в котором конечные точки удалены (иначе регулярное выражение не сработает). `implode("|", array_map(function($i) { return preg_quote(trim($i), "/"); }, $exp))` необходимо для экранирования точек.

Функция будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
function upper_letter($text){
    $exp = ['т.д','т.п','др','г','чел','пр', 'см'];
    $pattern = '/\b(?i:' . implode("|", array_map(function($i) { return preg_quote(trim($i), "/"); }, $exp)) . ')\b\.?(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\.\s*\w/u';  // добавляем модификатор u, чтобы регулярка работала с многобайтными кодировками (utf-8, utf-16)
    echo preg_replace_callback(
        $pattern,
        function($m) { // на вход поступает каждое из найденных соответствий 
            return  mb_strtoupper($m[0]); // используем mb_ функцию, так как она работает с многобайтными кодировками  
    }, $text);
}
```

См. [пример использования](https://3v4l.org/rsX8r):

```
upper_letter('Я охотник. живу в лесу.и мне комфортно и т.п');
// => Я охотник. Живу в лесу.И мне комфортно и т.п
upper_letter('См. тут. я читал и др. произведения. в 2003 г. никто об этом не знал. и т.д. и т.п');
// => См. тут. Я читал и др. произведения. В 2003 г. никто об этом не знал. И т.д. и т.п
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function i_ucfirst($str){
    $str = explode(' ', $str);
    
    foreach($str as &$val){
        $fstr = $val;
        if(!preg_match('/\w{1}\./', $fstr)){
            $fc = mb_strtoupper(mb_substr($fstr, 0, 1));
            $val = $fc.mb_substr($fstr, 1);
        };
    };
        
    return implode(' ', $str);
};
    
$foo = 'привет буфет ёпт и.т.д - и.т.п';
$foo = i_ucfirst($foo);

echo $foo
```

;

Вернёт  Привет Буфет Ёпт и.т.д - и.т.п

Выражение данного случая '/\w{1}./' можно дополнить другими  символами '/\w{1}[.,:!]/'

Например сокращённые слова будут через запятую или двоеточие  ........

Думаю это эффективнее preg_replace_callback на коротких строках :(